# ORS refuse to separate output record to new line

Tags: awk, sh

Hello guys i have this file:

```
paumic@os:~/l26$ cat p1
cat dog cow
cat dog mouse
dog cow cat
```

so what I want to do is to get first 2 columns and have them like this:

```
cat dog
cat dog
dog cow
```

when i use my script which is:

```
paumic@os:~/l26$ cat skript
#!/bin/sh    
output=$(cat $1 | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n"} {print $1, $2}' )
echo $output
```

i get answer:

```
paumic@os:~/l26$ ./skript p1
cat dog cat dog dog cow
```

If I use something else instead of `\n` it works. Example:

```
paumic@os:~/l26$ cat skript
#!/bin/sh
output=$(cat $1 | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="()"} {print $1, $2}' )
echo $output

paumic@os:~/l26$ ./skript p1
cat dog()cat dog()dog cow()
paumic@os:~/l26$
```

Thank you for you time and help.

Comment: `echo "$ouput"` as the dbl-quote prevent shell from stripping extra white-space. Good luck.

Comment: What shellter said, with emphasis. *Always* quote your variables. You may not always need to, but it's a much better habit to be in than not quoting them.  Also [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Thanks. Can you make answer instead of commend so i can close it as answered?

Comment: @ghoti if I dont use cat I get error message `[3] p1 not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always quote your variables.  It may not always be required, but it's a much safer habit to be in.

Also, you can streamline your use of `awk` and include error handling for missing options implicitly:

```
output=$(awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n"} {print $1 ORS $2}' "${1:?No file provided}" )
echo "$output"
```

Though it would probably be better to be explicit with your error handling:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: no file specified" >&2
  exit 1
elif [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: no such file '$1'" >&2
  exit 1
elif [ ! -r "$1" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: file unreadable: '$1'" >&2
  exit 1
elif [ ! -s "$1" ]; then
  echo "WARNING: file empty: '$1'" >&2
fi

output=$(awk -v ORS="\n" '{print $1,$2}' "$1" )

echo "$output"
```